# Replace Excel data with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have two excel sheets. One with formula and one without. Now I want to get the data from the Excel Sheet with Formula and replace it.

```
    data_read_only = list()
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
    ws = wb['Abschätzung SD Intern ']

    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            data_read_only.append(cell.value)




    wb: Workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=False)
    ws: Worksheet = wb['Abschätzung SD Intern ']

    for element in data_read_only:
        print(element)
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                ws.cell(row=row, column=cell).value = element

    wb.save(filename)
```

How can I replace the rows?

Comment: Try looking at [Copy data from one excel sheet to another using openpyxl in Python](https://www.codespeedy.com/copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-using-openpyxl-in-python/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=A948F11BBE5C4ACE9E986009A11ED253).

Comment: Thnaks Mate !!!